# Mosaic to New Raster: Mosaic has different max values than component rasters - ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, mosaic

I'm currently working on creating a raster mosaic of NDVI means for my province. It involves 12 input rasters, each with varying min-max values but all with 1 band, 32 bit floating pixels, and the same cell size. For whatever reason when I run the Mosaic to New Raster tool the max value of the mosaic is lower than the max value of some of the input rasters.

For example, my mosaic min value is -0.545024 and max value is 0.883919 but the input rasters can have max values up to 0.918612 and min values near -0.71.

I made sure to calculate statistics for the individual rasters as I was adding them to my table of contents. And, I ran into the same issue when creating a mosaic for the NDVI median for my province -- max values are higher in the individual rasters compared to the mosaic of all of them combined.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is cell size of mosaiced raster?

Comment: Hey Felix! The cell size is 10, 10. But, my colleague and I just figured out what was going on! For whatever reason, ArcPro was not displaying the real values for the min-max values of the mosaic. When I ran the Mosaic to Raster Tool, I was sure to set the pixel type to 32 bit float like the source rasters. For whatever reason, we needed to convert the mosaic to a float again and that changed the values to match the min-max of the source rasters. No clue why this is the case, since it should have been a float already when I ran the tool, but it solved our issue at least.